# ember-cli error on creating new application

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

I have windows system and have installed node v4.2.6, npm v2.14.12. I used following command to install ember cli `npm install -g ember-cli`. It is shows `v 0.0.39` for `ember -v` command.

On ember-cli website the current version is 1.35.15. It is confusing me if I have installed the correct version?

With this version, I get following errors on creating the ember application

```
ember-workspace>ember new dashbaord-app
version: 0.0.39
installing
  create .bowerrc
  create .jshintrc
  create Brocfile.js
  create README.md
  create app/app.js
  create app/components/.gitkeep
  create app/controllers/.gitkeep
  create app/helpers/.gitkeep
  create app/index.html
  create app/models/.gitkeep
  create app/router.js
  create app/routes/.gitkeep
  create app/styles/.gitkeep
  create app/styles/app.css
  create app/templates/.gitkeep
  create app/templates/application.hbs
  create app/templates/components/.gitkeep
  create app/views/.gitkeep
  create bower.json
  create config/environment.js
  create .gitignore
  create package.json
  create public/.gitkeep
  create testem.json
  create tests/.jshintrc
  create tests/helpers/resolver.js
  create tests/helpers/start-app.js
  create tests/index.html
  create tests/test-helper.js
  create tests/unit/.gitkeep
  create vendor/.gitkeep
Installing packages for tooling via npm._http_client.js:50
    throw new TypeError('Request path contains unescaped characters.');
    ^

TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters.
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:50:11)
    at TunnelingAgent.exports.request (http.js:31:10)
    at TunnelingAgent.createSocket (C:\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:117:25)
    at TunnelingAgent.createSecureSocket [as createSocket] (C:\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:184:41)
    at TunnelingAgent.addRequest (C:\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:80:8)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:132:16)
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10)
    at Object.exports.request (https.js:167:15)
    at Request.start (C:\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:583:30)
    at Request.end (C:\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1237:28)
```

Can anyone please help me if I am using correct packges and versions?
Thanks

Comment: That's definitely not the right version! I would suggest asking in the Slack group to help debug your environment more easily

Comment: Is this a google group?

Comment: It's similar, it's a chat application. You can join at this URL: https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com/